# Change password of SDF database file (SQL Server Compact 4.0)

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I would like to change the password of my SQL Server Compact 4.0 database. Is this possible out of Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate, SP1)? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as soon as I posted the question here, I found the solution.
First right-click on .sdf file in Visual Studio's Server Explorer and choose database properties.

[image]

In the new dialog there is a possibility to change the password:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Screen captures in VS 2012 Professional:

[image: Server Explorer > Database Properties]

[image: Database Properties > Set Password]